# How to change the controller class name in Zend Framework

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

For example, we have index controller:

```
class IndexController{ ...
```

How to make e.g.

```
class Index_Controller{ ...
```

work?

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried it myself *(and wouldn't really recommend doing this : knowing how classes are nammed is nice, because they follow the standard, when you start working on an existsing ZF-based project !)*, but there might be a solution ; see the following section from the manual : [12.6.2. Subclassing the Dispatcher](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.dispatcher.html#zend.controller.dispatcher.subclassing)

At the bottom of the page, it says *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> **Possible reasons to subclass the dispatcher include a desire to use a
>   different class or method naming
>   schema in your action controllers**,
>   or a desire to use a different
>   dispatching paradigm such as
>   dispatching to action files under
>   controller directories (instead of
>   dispatching to class methods).

So, this might help you do what you're asking -- once again, I've never this seen done, so I can't say for sure, but I hope this will give a hint to the final solution...

Answer (score 1):

As [Pascal MARTIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464032/how-to-change-the-controller-class-name-in-zend-framework/1464147#1464147) suggested, subclassing the dispatcher is the right way to go - even I'd share his opinion that deviating from the given ZF-naming convention should be well-founded.

`Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Abstract` provides two methods that determine the name of the controller class and the action method respectively:

```
public function formatControllerName($unformatted)
{
    return ucfirst($this->_formatName($unformatted)) . 'Controller';
}

public function formatActionName($unformatted)
{
    $formatted = $this->_formatName($unformatted, true);
    return strtolower(substr($formatted, 0, 1)) . substr($formatted, 1) . 'Action';
}
```

You can just subclass `Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Abstract` and override one or both methods to match your required naming convention.